# PHP: postgresql & Apache unique page not loading

Tags: php, postgresql, drupal, phppgadmin

All,
We have a page connected to a database in which a colleague created and now have some issues. I am a newbie so trying to get some clues about what to do.

I launch the services from the server called "Apache2.4" & "postgres" so that we can get the page loaded like we have in the past but for the past week, we have not been able to access the home page. It would not load.

The page uses php (drupal), postgresql, & webservices to store the data on the postgre db. Appears that the sql tables still work in the background as data is loading.

I can access the database linked to it. Just cannot get the page to load.

I looked at the Apache error logs but don't see anything that sticks out.

Here is what I get from IE:

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => theme_registry:runtime:bartik:cache ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of E:\xampp\htdocs\PXLSurveyManagement\includes\lock.inc).
Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => theme_registry:runtime:bartik:cache ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of E:\xampp\htdocs\PXLSurveyManagement\includes\lock.inc).
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {sessions} sessions WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (ssid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => yY-z98pxi4VHO8Gfa9Z5zab7ziJ2CudZqJoRbLP_GNw [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => ) in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of E:\xampp\htdocs\PXLSurveyManagement\includes\session.inc).
Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 710989903594eb2aad49014.33574397 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of E:\xampp\htdocs\PXLSurveyManagement\includes\lock.inc).

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "cannot get the page to load"? Are you saying that it won't ever complete loading (hangs) or that it loads, but with nothing displayed?

Comment: My advice: find somebody competent IRL to help you out. It's impossible to give you advices with the few informations of your question.

Comment: Thanks. The page just stays in loading mode but nothing displays. I can provide more information if I knew where to look. I am mainly looking for advice on where to look for possible error logs or basic toubleshooting. Would you like me to provide the index.php file?

Comment: I have this message from the php_error_log that started on the day the issues started: cannot set connection to blocking mode on both pg_query & pg_query_params